# PostActive visibility of class methods

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract

I have here this abstract base class called `base_class` defined as it follows:

```
class base_class
{
  public:
    virtual ~base_class() = 0 {}
    virtual size_t area() const = 0;

  protected:
    base_class() {}
};
```

One derived class from with it:

```
template <typename T> class A : public base_class
{
  public:
    A();
    ~A();

    size_t area() const;
    void display();

    (...) etc code
};
```

And another class still derived from it:

```
template <typename T> class B : public base_class
   {
     public:
       B();
       ~B();

       size_t area() const;
       void set();

       (...) etc code
   };
```

Than I have this instantiation and function call:

```
base_class *p = new A<int>;
p->display();

delete p;
p = new B<float>;
p->set();

(...) code
```

As you might already have observed, is that the pointer `p` won't "see" `display` and `set` methods.

---

The question is: when using pointers of type `base_class`, is there a chance of letting a derived object call derived methods that are only defined in the class that it points to? Thus being able to access display and set methods without having to make them virtual in the base class.

Otherwise we would have to make 2 virtual functions in the `base_class`, `display` and `set`, and that's very inconvenient, because `A` doesn't have to inherit `set` method, and `B` the `display` method.

Comment: If you know the actual runtime type of the object, you can `static_cast` the pointer to the derived type.

Comment: @T.C Could you elaborate? I'm not familiar with static_cast.

Comment: `base_class *p = new A<int>; static_cast<A<int> *>(p)->display();` Note that you really have to be sure that `p` is pointing to an `A<int>` otherwise you get undefined behavior.

Comment: It's known to be pointing to A<int>. Is static_cast in this context considered to be a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to *downcast* from base class to derived class, if could not determine the runtime type of the object.

```
base_class *p = new A<int>;
if (A<int> *pa = dynamic_cast<A<int> *>(p))
    pa->display();

delete p;
p = new B<float>;
if (B<float> *pb = dynamic_cast<B<float> *>(p))
    pb->set();
```

If the type of object could be confirmed at compile time, `static_cast` can do the cast too, but beware: You are telling the compiler that you know for a fact that what is being pointed to really is of that type. If you are wrong, then the cast cannot inform you of the problem (as could `dynamic_cast`, which would return a null pointer if the cast failed, or throw a `std::bad_cast` for a reference cast failure) and, at best, you will get spurious run-time errors and/or program crashes.

Anyway, the best practice should be rearrange the inheritance relationship, try to use virtual function, **avoid downcasts**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you ultimately want to do but its not usually good practice to call a function from the derived class that is not virtual in the base class using a pointer to a base class. As was already mentioned, you can use type casting to achieve this, but you need to check if the dynamic_cast was possible before attempting to call the function.

Have you considered creating a pure virtual function in the base class such as:

```
public:
  virtual void doIt() = 0;
```

Then you could implement this in the derived classes to call the function you want:

```
class A
{
void doIt()
{
    display();
}
};

class B
{
void doIt()
{
    set();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no way of accessing the members since for all the program knows it wouldn't have to be a derived class, and could just be the base class. This meaning casting as mentioned in the comments.

A pointer is simply an integer, for 32bit OS's it's a 32 bit int, for 64bit well i guess you could guess right? 64bit integer.

When it comes to typing pointers to actual classes and structures etc, it's up to the API to decide whether or not to display the function, it's more of a helper.

As for the program only knows it's a base class pointer you can only access it's variables. However if you are 100% sure what you are dealing with and you want to save performance here's something somewhat pseudo code.

```
typedef void (A::*func)(void*); 
func f = &A::set;
base_classPointer->*f();
```

But to be safe and sound either from the beginning make the pointer of the actual class as it seems you will be sure of that it's actually an A class.
Or use yourself of the dynamic, static, casts.

```
if(B * b = static_cast or dynamic_cast<B*>(mypointer))
```

Now I do suggest that you use yourself of exact pointer types if you are completely sure of what it's going to be. Or use yourself of the casts. If you are really anxious about performance, try the simple delegate method.